# The same BMI in method

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I've problem with my `JS code`. I made two objects with the same values. I want to decide which person has higher BMI. I made if statement but I think that console should log "`The same BMI`". It shows me that Mike has higher BMI.

```
var mark = {
  fullName: 'Mark',
  mass: 92,
  height: 1.93,
  bmi: function() {
    return this.mass/(this.height * this.height);
  }
};

var mike = {
  fullName: 'Mike',
  mass: 92,
  height: 1.93,
  bmi: function(){
    return this.mass/(this.height * this.height);
  }
};

var higherBMI = mark.bmi() > mike.bmi();

if (higherBMI === true) {
  console.log('Mark has higher BMI. He has ' + mark.bmi());
} else if (higherBMI === false) {
  console.log('Mike has higher BMI. He has ' + mike.bmi());
} else {
  console.log('The same BMI');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `>` operator which you are assigning to `higherBMI` returns false if mark.bmi is not higher than mike.bmi then when you test `else if (higherBMI === false)` it is true that higherBMI is false. That is why it is entering that block and logging 'Mike has higher BMI...' You need to test `else if mark.bmi() < mike.bmi();` then if both not true; not higher and not lower then it's equal.